# How can I shorten the use of this function? Alexa/NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have this function that I am using to return a slot value. If the slot is a synonym, it will revise the synonym to the canonical slot value. Here is the code I have now:

```
var slotHelper = function() { };

slotHelper.prototype.slotValue = (slot, useId) => {
    let value = slot.value;
    let resolution = (
        slot.resolutions
        && slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority
        && slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority.length > 0
    )
        ? slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0]
        : null;
    if (resolution && resolution.status.code == 'ER_SUCCESS_MATCH') {
        let resolutionValue = resolution.values[0].value;
        value = resolutionValue.id && useId
            ? resolutionValue.id
            : resolutionValue.name;
    }
    return value;
};

//Example
//let category = slotValue(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.category, true);

module.exports = new slotHelper();
```

I am trying to shorten the //example to where I can just type this:

```
let category = slotHelper.slotValue(category);
```

And return the canonical slot value.

I have tried some different approaches and they all result in: "Error handled: category is not defined"

Here are the different approaches I tried:

```
var slotHelper = function() { };

slotHelper.prototype.slotValue = (slotName, useId) => {
    let slot = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots[slotName];
    let value = slot.value;
    let resolution = (
        slot.resolutions
        && slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority
        && slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority.length > 0
    )
        ? slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0]
        : null;
    if (resolution && resolution.status.code == 'ER_SUCCESS_MATCH') {
        let resolutionValue = resolution.values[0].value;
        value = resolutionValue.id && useId
            ? resolutionValue.id
            : resolutionValue.name;
    }
    return value;
}

module.exports = new slotHelper();
```

AND

```
var slotHelper = function() { };

slotHelper.prototype.slotValue = (slotName, useId) => {
    let slot = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.slotName;
    let value = slot.value;
    let resolution = (
        slot.resolutions
        && slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority
        && slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority.length > 0
    )
        ? slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0]
        : null;
    if (resolution && resolution.status.code == 'ER_SUCCESS_MATCH') {
        let resolutionValue = resolution.values[0].value;
        value = resolutionValue.id && useId
            ? resolutionValue.id
            : resolutionValue.name;
    }
    return value;
}

module.exports = new slotHelper();
```

Of course, with the second one slotName is greyed out because that's not the right approach. Does anyone have any idea how I can revise this to where I can use:

```
let category = slotHelper.slotValue(category);
```

I am trying to generalize this function so that I can use it for all my slots in the future. This would make it easier to work with in my code... instead of always having to put:

```
let category = slotHelper.slotValue(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.category);
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion that might help eliminate a lot of the boilerplate introduced by checking if your `resolutionsPerAuthority` array exists could be to use [lodash's `head`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#head) method:

```
const resolution = _.head(slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority);
```

`_.head` can handle null or empty array input, so this should help shrink a lot of the cognitive overhead of your function down.

Comment: I'm not really worried about that, I really just want to be able to use slotHelper.slotValue(slotName); instead of a big line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. I had to put:

```
let categories = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.category;
```

and

```
let category = slotHelper.slotValue(categories);
```

In my index.js (main file) instead of the helper function because the index.js uses the ask-sdk to build responses. The module I created didn't have that capability.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this function](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-the-foodie/blob/b754bc11ffcc3ff222c430f21fb746744c19a932/lambda/custom/index.js#L728) as it's the helper you're looking for